# Visual Studio: automatically open Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, intellisense

Is there a way to make Intellisense(CTRL+Space) automatically open after I type a letter?  Its really annoying me to have to press CTRL+Space every line of code

Comment: It automatically shows by deafult. (At least with C# default environment settings).

Comment: IntelliSense was completely redone for C++ in VS2010.  You have to specify the version of VS you are using.

Comment: Im using 2008, but it doesnt do it in 2010 either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default C++ IntelliSense does not open automatically when you are typing except for after `.`, `->` and `::`.  The third party commercial extension [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) does provide that behavior though.

Answer (score 8):

What you describe is the default behavior.  To restore it, use:

- Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# (e.g.)
- Statement Completion -> Auto list members: Checked

**Edit:**

In C++ "Auto list members" does not apply to the first identifier in an expression, that is, when the identifier could be almost anything: a global variable, a keyword, a class member, etc.  It does however apply (and does work) after the ".", "->", and "::" operators.

A workaround for a very common case of desiring auto listing for class members is to use the "this->" convention in your code, which some coding standards recommend anyway.  The completion list will pop up immediately upon typing "->".